# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sin^4 x \cos^4 x}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

The integral in question is:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{\sin^4 x \cos^4 x} dx$$

I tried using $1 = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$, but it takes me nowhere.

Another try was converting it into $\sec$ and $\csc$, but some factors of cosec always remained when I substituted $\sec x$ as t.

Please give a pointer to where I should proceed. Thank you!

Comment: Our function is basically $1/\sin^4(2x)$. This is I think $\csc^2(2x)(\cot^2(2x)+1)$, or something like that. Now there is an easy substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the substitution $x=\arctan t$ we have $dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin^2(x)=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$, $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$, hence
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sin^4(x)\cos^4(x)} = \int\frac{(1+t^2)^3}{t^4 }\,dt $$
and the last integral is straightforward to compute through the binomial formula. It equals:
$$ C-\frac{1}{3 t^3}-\frac{3}{t}+3 t+\frac{t^3}{3}.$$

Comment: wow how did you get that idea?, simply amazing.

Comment: Very nice job. A clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

$(\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x))^4=\frac{\sin(2x)^4
}{16}$ . I think it's easy now by converting it to $\tan(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $$1=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2=\sin^4x+\cos^4x+2\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$$

Now $\int\sec^4x\ dx=\int(1+\tan^2x)\sec^2x\ dx=?$